# Who to call to cut an opening for bathroom vent?

Tags: vent, exhaust-fan

We just bought a house and the upstairs bathroom fan is venting into the soffits. The inspector said we would need someone to come in, cut an opening in the soffit, pull the vent through, and install a cap. I'm not sure what type of company to call for this though, so if anyone is able to point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: The neighbourhood handyman should be able to do it.  The only problem being upstairs is the extra height on a ladder.  One or two helpers to hold the ladder to be safer.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically a job a handyman would do in North America.

If another part of the globe, it would be the equivalent to a "handyman".

Answer (score 0):

In my part of the world  an electrician would do it.  But heat pump installers may be bothered to do it.

Its possibly simple enough for you to do it,  if you get a kit.

Comment: OP is asking about extending a bathroom vent pipe.  A pair of tin snips and a couple of small vent parts(a cap and extension) is all that is needed.  Plus not falling off the ladder.